# Create comma separated list from array in laravel/blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I am displaying elements of an array `@foreach($tags as $tag)$tag->@endforeach`. The output is `tag1tag2tag3`. What is the possible way to sho elements of array in `tag1,tag2,tag3`. And how to not show`,` if there is only one element in array.

Comment: Check implode - http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`implode()` is good for echoing simple data. In real project you usually want to add some HTML or logic into the loop, use [`$loop`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable) variable which is available since 5.3:

```
@foreach ($arrayOrCollection as $value)
    {{ $loop->first ? '' : ', ' }}
    <span class="nice">{{ $value->first_name }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: If there is only one element in array comma won't appear right ?

Comment: @ZacharyDale yes, you're right, you'll not see comma in this case.

Answer (score 62):

The selected answer is too complicated. Laravel has a simpler solution:

```
{{ $items->pluck('tag')->implode(', ') }}
```

Comment: How would wrap each element in anchor tag? And ideally, display "..." when a list is "too long"?

Answer (score 7):

Use this. We can implement it using **$loop->last**

```
@foreach ($arrayOrCollection as $value)
    <span class="nice">
        {{ $value->first_name }}

        @if( !$loop->last)
        ,
        @endif
    </span>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 4):

Use implode:

```
{{ implode(', ', $tags) }}
```

Comment: In Laravel you often deal with Collection objects instead of raw PHP arrays. In those cases, Collection provides an implode method itself. Use it like
`{{ $user->sports->pluck('name')->implode(', ') }}`

Answer (score 1):

implode is one option or you can using join as well like this

```
{{ join(', ', $tags) }}
```

Try the first one or this one..
good luck

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for might be something like this:
//have your array in php tags
//$arr = ['one', 'two', 'three']; ? >
//go through the array with foreach and if the count of the array is not equal to the las element then put coma after it

```
@foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    @if( count( $arr ) != $key + 1 )
        {{ $value }},
     @else
        {{ $value }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implode():

```
$arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
echo implode(',', $arr);
```

// output

```
one,two,three
```