# How to remove comma from last array in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this view :

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>
@foreach($journal->user as $item)
        {{ $item->name }},
@endforeach
</strong></p>
```

I wanted to remove comma after the last {{ $item->name }} string. How to do it in Laravel 5.3 blade ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using 5.3, you can use [$loop](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable) variable for this:

```
@foreach($journal->user as $item)
    {{ $loop->first ? '' : ', ' }}
    {{ $item->name }}
@endforeach
```

The code is from [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673923/create-comma-separated-list-from-array-in-laravel-blade).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
   @foreach($journal->user as $item)
        {{ $item->name }}
        @if (!$loop->last)
        ,
        @endif
   @endforeach
```